# Sub Class QAbstractCameraController PyQt

Tags: camera, pyqt, qt3d

I can not sub class QAbstractCameraController in PyQt3D. Is this a bug?

```
class FemapCameraController(QAbstractCameraController):

def __init__(self, rootEntity):
    super(FemapCameraController, self).__init__(rootEntity)
    ...
```

TypeError: PyQt5.Qt3DExtras.QAbstractCameraController cannot be instantiated or sub-classed

Comment: There's no point in asking questions like that here, because the author of pyqt3d will never see them. Bug reports need to be posted to the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).